# Subtract two Date/Time columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How do I subtract two Date/Time columns in Power BI.

If I have:

[image]

How do I find out the time difference between Last Updated and Created Time (in hours)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is called "Table":

```
Time Difference = DATEDIFF('Table'[Created Time], Table[Last Updated], DAY)
```

DATEDIFF Function description:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/datediff-function-dax